# Shape parameter of gamma full conditional tau is too small, WinBUGS

Tags: bayesian, markov-chains, mcmc, winbugs, gamma

I'm trying to code a reserving model and I'm encountering some problems:

1. When I press "load inits", I get the message

   > this chain contains unitialized variables

   although I've initialized all my variables.
2. Ignoring the first problem and pressing "gen inits" when I try to update my model, I get the message

   > shape parameter of gamma full conditional too small

   although the parameters of gamma distribution that I use are the same that Ntzoufras and Dellaportas (2002) at "BAYESIAN MODELLING OF OUTSTANDING LIABILITIES INCORPORATING CLAIM COUNT UNCERTAINTY" suggest.

Here is the WinBUGS code:

```
#MODEL
model {

for (i in 1:n) {

for (j in 1:n){

x[i,j] ~ dlnorm(m[i,j], t)

m[i,j] <- c + a[i] + b[j]

} 

a[1] <- -sum(a[2:n])

b[1] <- -sum(b[2:n])

c ~ dnorm(0,0.001)

for (i in 2:n) {

a[i] ~ dnorm(0, 0.01)

b[i] ~ dnorm(0,0.01) }

t ~ dgamma(0.001, 0.001)

sigma2 <- 1/t

R[1] <- 0

for (i in 2:n){

R[i] <- sum(x[i,(n+2-i):n])

}

Total <- sum(R[])

}
#DATA
list(n=10)

x[,1] x[,2] [,3] x[,4] x[,5] x[,6] x[,7] x[,8] x[,9] x[,10]

357848  766940  610542  482940 527326 574398 146342 139950 227229 67948

352118  884021  933894 1183289 445745 320996 527804 266172 425046 NA

290507 1001799  926219 1016654 750816 146923 495992 280405 NA NA

310608 1108250  776189 1562400 272482 352053 206286 NA NA NA

443160  693190  991983  769488 504851 470639 NA NA NA NA

396132  937085  847498  805037 705960 NA NA NA NA NA

440832  847631 1131398 1063269 NA NA NA NA NA NA

359480 1061648 1443370 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA

376686  986608 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA

344014 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA

END
#INITS



list(a=c(NA,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2),
b=c(NA,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0), c=10, t=10)
```